# can someone help me with a proxy list

Tags: c#

Okay someone said to put my proxies in a list so I can use a new proxy for each request, I have the proxies saved to a list but I am a little confused on where to go from here

This is the code that I used to generate the proxie list, and it's coming from a proxies.txt file.

```
    private List<string> getProxyListFromText(string input) {

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);
        string item = "";
        while (item != null)
        {
            item = reader.ReadLine();
            if (item != null)
            {
                list.Add(item);                


            }

        }
        reader.Close();          
        return list;



    }
```

ok here is the request, each request should retreive a different proxie from the list.

Picture a for loop that is looping through a list of names, each name brings up a different request, and each request should have it's own proxy, the proxy list is already generated in the code above just need a way i can retreive proxies from the list.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {

    object url;
                    WebClient wc;
                    url = getppl;
                    wc = new WebClient();

                //This should come from the proxy list
                wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(getProxyListFromText("Proxies.txt"));

                    var page = wc.DownloadString(url.ToString());
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadHtml(page);
                    var pplname = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/p");
     }
```

I tried a nested for loop but the logic got tied up somewhere.

Comment: Don't just close the stream but also dispose of it

Comment: ok i think im just going to put the proxies in a listbox and randomly select them.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:-

```
foreach(string prox in getProxyListFromText("Proxies.txt"))
{
 ...
 wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(prox);
 ...
}
```

Comment: thank you how would you go about selecting a random line from the proxies.txt file?